# Multiple keyboards same letter fires one keypress

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

i am using the latest Linux Mint distro with two external keyboards connected to a laptop. Both are identical. Logitech K120

If I press letter <kbd>a</kbd> on both keyboards at the same time it seems that it only fires one keypress event. Result in the keyboard is: single `a` instead of `aa`.

If i press <kbd>a</kbd> on 1st keyboard and <kbd>b</kbd> on the 2nd one it works as expected: `ab`

I tried typing this in a console. Also checked in the browser by capturing and outputting all keypress events. When same letter pressed on both keyboards it fires only one event. When different letters - two separate events.

Note: I've also used `xkbcomp` to alter 2nd keyboard's layout in order to increase  original eventcode numbers (ex: keyCode + 2000). Im doing a multiplayer game with two keyboards and one PC. Altering is needed to determine in JavaScript which keyboard sent what code.. (I decrease values in JavaScript to get actual typed characters).